# Proof that we get equivalent system by applying elementary row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A$ be system of liner equations. And let $A\leadsto A'$ mean that we got $A'$ by applying elementary row operations to $A$. Let $p_{ij}$ represent row switching, $q_{ij}(K)$ represent row addition and $r_i(K)$ represent row multiplication with $K$ where $K$ is not $0$.

Claim: If $A\leadsto A'$ then $A' \leadsto A$ and $S(A) = S(A')$ i.e. systems are equivalent.

From the fact that every elementary operation has its own inverse then it means that we can get $A' \leadsto A$. **If $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3...c_n)$ is a solution to $A$ then then $c$ is solution to systems $p_{ij}(A)$, $q_{ij}(K)(A)$, $r_i(K)(A)$.** So elementary transformations translate system into equivalent system. After finite number of elementary transformation we get $S(A)=S(A')$. qed.

While i intuitive understand that if for example we switch places of two equations in system $A$ and get system $A'$, when we plug in $c$ we will find out that c is a solution to $A'$. But where is the proof of the bolded sentence? That's whats is tripping me in this proof. In other words why is the case that "If $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3...c_n)$ is a solution to $A$ then then $c$ is solution to systems $p_{ij}(A)$, $q_{ij}(K)(A)$, $r_i(K)(A)$."

Answer (score 0):

The relevant fact is that any sequence of elementary row operations on a matrix $A$ can be achieved by left-multiplying $A$ by an invertible matrix. (Indeed, you can obtain such a matrix by multiplying the elementary matrices corresponding to the row operations you have performed.) With this fact, we can proceed.

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and let $b\in\mathbb{F}^m$ be a vector. Also, let $E$ be an  invertible $m\times m$ matrix. Then, a vector $x\in\mathbb{F}^n$ satisfies $Ax=b$ if and only if $(EA)x=Eb$. (This is really a consequence of our being able to multiply by $E^{-1}$.) We have shown that the systems $Ax=b$ and $(EA)x=Eb$ are equivalent in the sense that they have exactly the same solutions $x$.